# Typescript types from .d.ts file are not visible in the application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I was trying to type useContext hook and found this blog post https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-context-with-typescript/
as author wrote

- The type.d.ts file that contains the TypeScript Types. The extension .d.ts allows using the types in other files without importing them

and the example shows usage like so:

```
const { saveTodo } = React.useContext(TodoContext) as ContextType
```

so I have created contexts.d.ts and inside I declared a type like so

```
import type { UserMetrics } from "../components";
type UserMetricsContextType = {
  userMetrics: UserMetrics;
  setUserMetrics: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserMetrics>>;
};
```

and when I try to use it in the application, I get:

```
type UserMetricsContextType = /*unresolved*/ any
```

Could you please explain what am I doing wrong?

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "include": ["assets/*", "components/*", "types/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you include this file in the `include` property of your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @SethLutske yes I did, I made an update with my tsconfig.json